# Check single element into ArrayList with multiple column

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList <Elem> list=new ArrayList <Elem>();
```

where

```
class Elem{
public String name;
public int a;
public int b;
}
```

I add several different objects into this ArrayList where each object contains 3 elements - String, int, int.

Now I would like know if a Name, given in input, is already in the ArrayList.
How I can do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a [`HashMap<String, Elem>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of a list for search operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Java 8 you should give it a try:

```
list.parallelStream().filter(elem -> elem.getName().equals(name)).findAny().isPresent();
```

It works very fast for massive lists and returns true if the name can be found in list' elements (false otherwise).

**Update:** If you want to get not only flag, that element with the given name can be found, but the element itself and its values you should use something like:

```
Optional<Elem> elemOpt = list.parallelStream().filter(elem -> elem.getName().equals(name)).findAny();

if(elemOpt.isPresent()){
    //do some logic with element if exists
    Elem elem = elemOpt.get();
    System.out.println(elem.getName());
    System.out.println(elem.getA());
    System.out.println(elem.getB());
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have a new question. As said I have some elem into list, if I know the value of a String that identify one of elem among the other, how I can obtain  the value of the other components? e.g., list={"john",3,4, "marc,4,3"}; If I know that the value "marc" how I can obtain as out 4,3?

Comment: ok, feel free to upvote and mark my answer as a solution then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambdas since java 8...

Or you iterate the list and break when fount the Element

## Example:

```
List<Elem> l=new ArrayList<Elem>();
boolean flag = false;
for (Elem elem : l) {
if (elem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("myNameTest")) {
    flag = true;
    break;
}
    
if (flag) {
    System.out.println("Element found");
}
```